# I want to change the style when the input is focused In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [isInput, setIsInput] = useState(false);
const inputRef = useRef(null);

const clickHandler = () => {
  if (inputRef.current) {
    setIsInput(true);
  } else {
      
  }
};

const changeHandler = (e) => {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
};

return (
  <header className={classes.header}>
    <div className={classes.search}>
      <GoSearch
        className={classes.searchIcon}
        style={{ color: isInput ? 'white' : '#cccccc' }}
      />
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        className={classes.searchInput}
        onClick={clickHandler}
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  </header>
);
```

I want to change the style(white) when the input is focused In React

And I want to apply the exisiting style(#cccccc) when the input is not focused

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) will help?

Comment: I want to change <GoSearch /> style when the input focus

Comment: See my Answer below is this helpful ?

Comment: Then maybe use `onFocus` and `onBlur` on input and add another flag to state like "isInputFocused". Depending on this change styles for GoSearch component.

Comment: Thank you capchuck, I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using CSS focus.

```
.searchIcon {
  color: #cccccc;
}
.searchInput:focus .searchIcon {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: In this style, the searchIcon color is always white. But what i need is to change the seachIcon style only when the input is focused

Comment: The fourth line `.searchInput:focus .searchIcon {` is only change the color to white or any other when `.searchInput` is focus.

Comment: I tested but there is no change in searchIcon color

Comment: Perhaps @Lee, what you are trying to achieve requires a stylesheet instead of your inline style. Bill's answer is correct but I've created a sandbox here for you as a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-forest-e19sm?file=/src/index.js